# installing js traverse

Tags: node.js, traversal

i installed js traverse by

```
npm install traverse
```

and doing

```
hash = require('traverse/hash'),
```

give me error that

```
traverse/has module not defined
```

and if i do

```
hash = require('traverse'),
```

give me error that

```
update method is not defined
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Hash = require('hashish');
```